# mySQL Left Join on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm really struggling with this query. I have 4 tables (http://oberto.co.nz/db-sql.png):

Invoice_Payement, Invoice, Client and Calendar. I'm trying to create a report by summing up the 'paid_amount' col, in Invoice_Payment, by month/year.

- The query needs to include all months, even those with no data
- There query needs the condition (Invoice table): registered_id = [id]

I have tried with the below query, which works, but falls short when 'paid_date' does not have any records for a month. The outcome is that month does not show in the results

I added a Calendar table to resolved this but not sure how to left join to it.

```
SELECT 
   MONTHNAME(Invoice_Payments.date_paid) as month, 
   SUM(Invoice_Payments.paid_amount) AS total
FROM Invoice, Client, Invoice_Payments
WHERE Client.registered_id = 1
AND Client.id = Invoice.client_id
And Invoice.id = Invoice_Payments.invoice_id
AND date_paid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(Invoice_Payments.date_paid), MONTH(Invoice_Payments.date_paid)
```

Please see the above link for a basic ERD diagram of my scenario.

Database: http://oberto.co.nz/
Expected output: my current query, below, will return something like:

```
month       total
August      5
September   0
October  196
November  205
December  214
January  229
```

Thanks for reading.
I've posted this Q before but I think I worded it badly.

Comment: Do you want just a list of totals for each month?  Why do you need "date_paid IS NOT NULL" in your WHERE clause?  Are there actually payments in your Invoice_Payments table with null date_paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated :P, Will this work?

```
SELECT YEAR(calendar.date_field) as year,
 MONTHNAME(calendar.date_field) as month,
 SUM(Invoice_Payments.paid_amount) AS total 
FROM calendar
 left outer join invoice_Payments on calendar.date_field = invoice_Payments.date_paid
 left outer join Invoice on invoice_payments.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
 left outer join (select * from client where registered_id = 1) as c on c.id = Invoice.client_id
GROUP BY YEAR(calendar.date_field), MONTH(calendar.date_field)
```

Comment: Not quite, but thanks. It works except it doesn't display months with missing Invoice_Payments.date_paid records. That is why I assume I need to do a left join on the Calendar table.

Comment: Almost! All the data is returning correctly except the restriction ...and Client.registered_id = 1 is being ignored. So I get data returned for all Id's and not a specified Id. Is this an easy fiX?

Comment: I added Client.registered_id to the SELECT just to see the output. The incorrect months show id=NULL, while the correct months show 1, as expected. Not sure if this helps you or not?

Comment: Try changing the left outer join client to a join.

Comment: Nope, this takes a back to square one - missing months with no data

Comment: left outer join (select * from Client where registered_id = 1) as c on invoice.client_id = c.client_id

Comment: Now I get: Unknown column 'c.client_id' in 'on clause'. So I changed c.client_id to c.id (which I think is correct) but then we back to the incorrect months showing. I.E, the registered_id = 1 not working

Comment: Now I don't know how hard core you are, but I did attach a copy of the DB and the expected results. I know it's a bit check :P

Comment: remove the registered_id = 1 from the main query, but leave it in the subquery. FYI, this is the subquery: (select * from Client where registered_id = 1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I much appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously that you are not doing a left join so a solution could be to rewrite the query to use a the join syntax where you can specify that you want a left join. Something like

Select * from invoice left join client on client.id=invoice.client_id left join

And so on

Comment: Thanks MTilsted. I understand I need a left join, and creating *just* a left join is something I can do, but when adding with the other conditions - I simply can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Well it looks like the correct query is just below this answer :}

Answer (score 0):

This can also work ...

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Invoice_Payments.date_paid) as month, SUM(Invoice_Payments.paid_amount) AS total
FROM Client
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice ON Client.id = Invoice.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_Payments ON Invoice.id = Invoice_Payments.invoice_id
WHERE Client.registered_id = 1 AND date_paid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(Invoice_Payments.date_paid), MONTH(Invoice_Payments.date_paid);
```

Comment: This question is over a year old. Can you explain how your answer improves on the existing query?